# Without using the beta function, find values $q,r$ such that the improper integral $\int_0^1 x^q (1-x^2)^r dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Question:**

> For what values $q,r$ does the improper integral $\int_0^1 x^q (1-x^2)^r dx$ converge?

I already have a solution to this using the beta function. I am looking for other possible solutions that **do not use the beta function** since it is a little advanced for what I have learned in my education so far.

I know the answer should be $q,r > -1$. As a possible hint for myself and others, it seems that the only issues are at the endpoints, since that is the only place the function can go to infinity.

Can others put forward alternative solutions?

Comment: Since you have $0<x<1$ then you can expand the brackets and integrate term by term and check the convergence of the series? But this is definitely not my area of expertise. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- At $0$ we have

$$x^q(1-x^2)^r\sim_0 x^q$$
and the integral
$$\int_0^1 x^qdx$$
is convergent if and only if $q>-1$.

- At $1$ we have
  $$x^q(1-x^2)^r\sim_1 2^r(1-x)^r$$
  and the integral $$\int_0^1(1-x)^rdx$$
  is convergent if and only if $r>-1$. Hence the given integral is convergent if and only if $q,r>-1$.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I understand your argument but, to clarify, how do we know that the integral cannot go to infinity anywhere else besides the endpoints?

Comment: The function $x\mapsto x^q(1-x^2)^r$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ so the only problem is at the endpoints.